# Getting a PS3 / Windows USB controller to work on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, 18.04, usb, games

I recently purchased a PS3/Windows controller that plugs in via USB, but no LEDS light up and xboxdrv does not detect it neither does jstest/jstest-gtk.

How do I get it working?
Ubuntu 18.04
Tried multiple USB ports

Answer (score 1):

Does it work anywhere else? What is the output of `sudo lsusb` ? Did you try a motherboard port (instead of the case ones... just checking). Since no leds light up, could be even a crappy cable - some cheap cables from e.g aliexpress are not very good to say the least.

...I of course also assume it's not an official Sony controller.

Comment: I think it's probably a bad controller because I couldn't even find a number or site connected to the controller. I have since returned it.